# django: How to render CharField as a label in Model Admin page?

Tags: django

My Model has a CharField called "comments". I want to display this as just a regular paragraph of text, instead of the default html textarea on the Model admin page. How would I go about implementing this change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be misunderstanding your question, but I think you want to take a look at Django's readonly_fields option.

```
readonly_fields = ('comments', )
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to [create a custom widget](http://joshourisman.com/2008/11/19/custom-fields-and-widgets-django-forms/) and override the `render()` method.

Comment: is there a way to change the widget at runtime? For example, choose the widget type based logged-in user's permissions